# Error propagatin inside try/catch in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exception, try-catch

I want to raise an exception inside a catch block of a method and handle it in catch of  another method from where earlier method was called.
I tried this logic-

```
method B()
{
    @try{
        .......
        // calling method where is probable chance of exception


    method A();
    }
    catch(NSException e)
    {
        //catching the exception thrown in the method B()
        NSString* theError=[e reason];
        NSLog(@"the error is == %@",theError);
    }
}

method A()
{
    @try{
        .............
        //throw an exception incase of some condition
        throw e;
    }
    catch(NSException e)
    {
        //rethrowing the exception, want to catch in the method from where this method is called.  
        throw e;
    }
}
```

But the catch block of method B() is never accessible.
The control never returns to the catch block of method B().
Please suggest.

Thanks,
    Sudhansu

---

Here is a bit of code. I am calling a method (populateData) of TableController from MyController.
The exception supposed to occur in another method of TableController(initializeTest) and i am throwing it
inside try block of FinderCompleted method. In the catch block of same method , rethrowing the exception, as
I don't want to handle it here.
The control is restricted only to the innermost catch block of method - (void)FinderCompleted:(id)args
the NSLog prints like this-
m here 1
Inside the error
You got nothing in ur bucket :D
Throwing exception for the 1st time
Gotcha--1st time exception , throwing it 2nd time
the error is == Something unexpected happened --EXCEPTION

After that i don't know where the control is going. I want the control to go catch block of the outer method which calls FinderCompleted method,
and print the other logs like-
Gotcha--2st time exception, throwing it 3rd time
Gotcha--3rd time exception
Throwing exception for the 4th time
Gotcha--4th time exception
the error is Something unexpected happened --EXCEPTION

---

```
in MyController.m

- (IBAction)fetchResults:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *tableColumnArray = ...............;//some values initialized
    NSArray *identifierArray = ................;//some values initialized
    NSArray *bindVariableArray = ................;//some values initialized
    TableController *pTC = [[TableController alloc] init];
    @try
    {
        [pTC populateData :tableColumnArray :identifierArray :bindVariableArray];// calling populate DataForMD method defined in  TableController class
        [pTC release];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e)
    {
        NSLog(@"Gotcha--4th time exception");
        //want to handle the exception here 
        NSString* theError=[e reason];
        NSLog(@"the error is %@",theError);
    }
}
```

---

in  TableController.m

```
-(void)populateData:(NSArray *)tableColumnArray:(NSArray *)identifierArray:(NSArray *)bindVariableArray
{
    [self setTableColumnArray:tableColumnArray];
    [self setColumnIdentifierArray:identifierArray];
    [self setBindVarArray:bindVariableArray];
    @try
    {
        NSLog(@"m here 1");
        [self initializeTest];// calling initializeTest method 
    }
    @catch (NSException * e)
    {
        //Do not want to handle it here 
        NSLog(@"Gotcha--3rd time exception");
        NSLog(@"Throwing exception for the 4th time");
        @throw e;
    }
}

-(void)initializeTest
{
    @try
    {
        ISTQuery* theQuery = (ISTQuery*)[ISTQueryGenerator getQueryByName:[self queryClassName]];
        ..........
        ...........//some loc here
        [theQuery run];
        .................//some loc here
        if(theQuery)
        {
            //Calling FinderCompleted method 
            //supposed to get error here
            [[self modelFinder] startWithRecipient:self andNotificationSelector:@selector(FinderCompleted:)];
        }
    }
    @catch(NSException *e) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Gotcha--2st time exception, throwing it 3rd time");
        //Do not want to handle it here 
        @throw e; // rethrows e implicitly
    }
}

- (void)FinderCompleted:(id)args
{
    @try
    {   //getting some error while back-end transaction 
        NSString* theError = [ISTModelFinder errorMessageFromFinderArgs:args];
        if (theError)
        {
            NSLog(@"Inside the error");
            NSLog(@"You got nothing in ur bucket :D");
            NSException *e = [NSException
                              exceptionWithName:@"InternalErrorException"
                              reason:@"Something unexpected happened --EXCEPTION"
                              userInfo:nil];
            NSLog(@"Throwing exception for the 1st time");
            @throw e;
        }       
        else
        {
            //do sth else
        }
    }   
    @catch(NSException *e) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Gotcha--1st time exception , throwing it 2nd time");
        NSString* theError=[e reason];
        //Do not want to handle it here 
        NSLog(@"the error is == %@",theError);
        @throw e; // rethrows e implicitly
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make an effort to indent your code properly to make it more readable.  I've done it for you just this once :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use exceptions for flow control in Cocoa or iOS programming.  Exceptions are purely for identifying unrecoverable errors and, typically, the program crashes purposefully very shortly thereafter.   (With a handful of exceptions to this rule, most of which have bugs filed against them to deprecate and eliminate the related API.)

Use the `NSError` pattern to manage user recoverable errors.

It isn't clear why your code isn't working.  But that doesn't look like real code.  What have you tried?

---

> I had added the code snippet, please suggest how to achieve that
>   functionality.

The first thing you do is *do not use exceptions*.

Use the NSError pattern.   You will need to refactor your code to do so.   It is worth it.

See the documentation on [error handling in cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html).

Comment: Without the asterisks following the `NSException`s will it even compile?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand bbum correctly. In Cocoa / Cocoa Touch you don't throw exceptions to handle unexpected errors. Instead you use NSError. The error can be _"thrown back"_ using an indirection pointer. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html

Comment: I had added the code snippet, please suggest how to achieve that functionality.